# Being integral is preserved by quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\varphi:B\rightarrow A$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings. We say that $\varphi$ is integral if every element of $A$ satisfies a polynomial equation with coefficients in $\varphi(B)$. I am trying to understand why the induced map $\varphi':B/J\rightarrow A/\varphi(J)A$ is also integral.

So, to start the obvious way, we know that there exists an $n\geq 1$ and some $b_i\in B$ such that $a^n+\varphi(b_{n-1})a^{n-1}+\cdots +\varphi(b_1)a+\varphi(b_0)=0$. But then simply reducing this equation mod $\varphi(J)A$ doesn't seem to work.

In particular, I don't see how reducing mod $\varphi(J)A$ tells us that the coefficients are in $\varphi'(B/J)$. What am I missing?

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand... Why doesn’t reducing mod $\varphi(J)A$ work?

Comment: @Mindlack I don't see how reducing mod $\varphi(J)A$ tells us that the coefficients are in $\varphi'(B/J)$.

Comment: The reduction of $\varphi(b)$ mod $\varphi(J)A$ is $\varphi'([b])$, where $[b]$ is the reduction of $b$ mod $J$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $[a] \in A/\varphi(J)A$. Since $\varphi$ is integral and $a \in A$, we have that
$$ a^n + \varphi(b_1) a^{n-1} + \dots + \varphi(b_n) = 0,$$
for some $n$ and $b_i \in B$. Thus, the following holds in $A/\varphi(J)A$
$$ [a]^n + [\varphi(b_1)] [a]^{n-1} + \dots + [\varphi(b_n)] = 0.$$
Recall that $\varphi'$ is defined as follows
\begin{align*}
\varphi' \colon B/J & \to A/ \varphi(J) A \\
[b] & \mapsto [\varphi(b)]. 
\end{align*}
Hence, $\varphi'([b_i]) = [\varphi(b_i)]$, which implies that
$$ [a]^n + \varphi'([b_1]) [a]^{n-1} + \dots + \varphi'([b_n]) = 0.$$
Since $[a]$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\varphi'$ is integral.